# How can I get a canvas image to detect and teleport to another canvas image?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program with images of roads that allows the user to build roads on a canvas. Currently, the user can select where the road goes, and it does not have to be connected to another road. 
Here is an example: (the road images are placed by the user)
[image]

What I want to happen is once the `Build Road(vertical)` or the `Build Road(horizontal)` is pressed, it will detect any already existing image of that road, and place it vertically or horizontally to it based on the button pressed. I know this sounds a bit far fetched, but here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("root")


road1 = PhotoImage(file=r"road1.png")
road2 = PhotoImage(file=r"road2.png")
road3 = PhotoImage(file=r"intersection.png")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, bg='green')

button_frame = Frame(root)

button_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
roadstart = canvas.create_image(100, 0, image=road1)

clickedv = None
clickedh = None
clickedm = None


def buildroadv():
    global clicked
    clickedv = False
    road = canvas.create_image(50, 50, image=road1)
    def move(event):
        global clickedv
        if clickedv == False:
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            canvas.coords(road, x, y)
    def placeroad(event):
        global clickedv
        clickedv = True
    canvas.tag_bind(road, "<Motion>", move)
    canvas.tag_bind(road, "<ButtonPress-1>", placeroad)

def buildroadh():
    global clickedh
    clickedh = False
    road = canvas.create_image(50, 50, image=road2)
    def move(event):
        global clickedh
        if clickedh == False:
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            canvas.coords(road, x, y)
    def placeroad(event):
        global clickedh
        clickedh = True
    canvas.tag_bind(road, "<Motion>", move)
    canvas.tag_bind(road, "<ButtonPress-1>", placeroad)

def buildroadm():
    global clickedm
    clickedm = False
    road = canvas.create_image(50, 50, image=road3)
    def move(event):
        global clickedm
        if clickedm == False:
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            canvas.coords(road, x, y)
    def placeroad(event):
        global clickedm
        clickedm = True
    canvas.tag_bind(road, "<Motion>", move)
    canvas.tag_bind(road, "<ButtonPress-1>", placeroad)



button1 = Button(button_frame, text="Build Road (vertical)", command=buildroadv)
button2 = Button(button_frame, text="Build Road (horizontal)", command=buildroadh)
button3 = Button(button_frame, text="Build Road (intersection)", command=buildroadm)
button4 = Button(button_frame, text="Build -")
button5 = Button(button_frame, text="Build -")
button6 = Button(button_frame, text="Build -")
button7 = Button(button_frame, text="Build -")
button8 = Button(button_frame, text="Build -")


button1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button4.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button5.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button6.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button7.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button8.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

To outline my goal again, I would like for the program to detect if there is already an existing `road`, and if there is, place the new road accordingly. For example:
[image]

I hope this explains enough. I apologise for such a specific question/broad answer.

Comment: What sort of help do you need? As written, this question is too broad, as it sounds like you're asking us to write the code for you. Can you be more specific about the type of help that you need?

Comment: @BryanOakley I'd like to know how I can detect if my canvas created image has already been placed - and if correct, how can I get a new image to go to the older images location? For example, there is a road here. When I click to get a new road, the program needs to check if a road already exists - if it does exist, it needs to place a road correlating with the first road. Is this specific enough?

Comment: So, what's stopping you from doing that? Since your code is creating the roads, why can't you just save the coordinates of each piece of road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is probably crazy overkill for what you are doing.  You can probably just use the coordinates from your last click to extract the dimensions and location of your road.  Unfortunately, without access to the images I can't test this so I figured I'd offer you a more general solution, one that will work even if you load an image like the one you provided onto a canvas, where there are no clicks to remember.  Besides, as some comments have pointed out, if you know the coordinates and dimensions of your road blocks already, placing them is trivial.  Just set the new road to be placed at the appropriate location, based on your saved values.  It gets a bit harder when you don't know where the roads are, that is, when you are looking at a raw image.  That's the problem I'll be looking at.  The basic tactic I took is to treat this like any other image processing/computer vision problem and find the roads as objects in the image.

The First step is to isolate the roads.  To do this, you can use a sobel filter to find the edges, followed by thresholding and a fill to turn them into solid blocks:

```
import imageio
import skimage
import numpy
import scipy.ndimage.filters
import skimage.io
import skimage.filters
import skimage.morphology


image = imageio.imread(r'C:\Users\Jeremiah\Pictures\roads.PNG')
image_array = numpy.float64(image)

#Sobel Filter for color image.  First the kernel is applied to the RGB values, then some linear algebra is done to marry the results together and apply them to the image as a whole.

R_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 0], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])
G_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 1], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])
B_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 2], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])

R_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 0], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
G_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 1], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
B_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 2], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])

Jacobian_x = R_x**2 + G_x**2 + B_x**2
Jacobian_y = R_y**2 + G_y**2 + B_y**2
Jacobian_xy = R_x * R_y + G_x * G_y + B_x * B_y
Determinant = numpy.sqrt(numpy.fabs((Jacobian_x**2) - (2 * Jacobian_x * Jacobian_y) + (Jacobian_y**2) + 4 * (Jacobian_xy**2)))
Maximum_Eigenvalue = (Jacobian_x + Jacobian_y + Determinant) / 2
Edges = numpy.sqrt(Maximum_Eigenvalue)

#A threshold is set, and a binary image is produced that sets everything above the threshold to 255 and everything below it to 0.

Threshold = skimage.filters.threshold_mean(Edges)
Binary_Image = Edges > Threshold   

#The holes in the objects are filled in, so that each road is a solid block.

Filled_Holes = scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes(Binary_Image)
```

Next, you label your blocks:

```
labeled_Edges, features = scipy.ndimage.label(Filled_Holes)
```

Now that you have labeled objects in an image, you can use the `labeled_Edges` slices as indices for where this block starts and stops.  `features` gives you the number of objects in the image.  As an example:

```
sliced = scipy.ndimage.find_objects(labeled_Edges)[3]
>>>(slice(127, 166, None), slice(37, 71, None))
```

if we use that slice as an index in the original image array, we get an array containing only the pixels for that object, labeled for your convenience:

```
slices = labeled_Edges[sliced]
>>>[[4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]
   [4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]
   [4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]
   ...
   [4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]
   [4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]
   [4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]]
```

The `4` just means that this is the fourth labeled object in the image, since we searched for `labeled_Edges[3]` in this case.  In practice, you would want to automate this using a `for` loop, with your range being set from 1 to `features`, but once you have your slices, your have the indices for the start and stop of any road tile, and you just place the edge of the next road tile on the next pixel.  So, in the case of the example above, our corners are at `(127, 37), (127, 71), (166, 37), and (166,71)`.  The placement of your next road can be automated just by using these corners.  For example, if you want to place a road block to the right of this one, and if you are referencing the block that you are placing using the upper left corner, the new road would be placed at `(166, 37)`.  To place the same block to the left of this one, using the same corner as an anchor, you would place it at `(127 - new_block_length, 37)`.

Unfortunately, some aspects of your question are rather non-specific.   Do you have the locations of the road images stored anywhere or do you need to have the program actually look at the image?  Do you want all possible horizontal roads placed when you hit "horizontal", or is there a method for referencing a particular road?  Are you placing the roads using the center pixel or one of the corners? There are just a lot of variables that prevent writing the code for this solution for you, but this may give you some ideas to try out, and at least get you looking at how you localize the objects in the image itself.

This answer is a bit broad but the question is a bit broad.  If you have the locations of your roads stored already, none of the computer vision stuff is necessary.  You just find the coordinates of the roads using simple variable calls and do the same thing, place your new road based on the location of the last road.

Comment: Thanks for this long answer, but sadly I don't want to be using skrimage/numpy ect. What I would like to do now is 'find the coordinates of the roads using simple variable calls', how do I do that? Can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: Well you have your x an y values for the placement of any manually placed roads stored as `x` and `y`.   You'd simply bind a `placeroad` function to the button that you want to press to perform this task that places a road tile at the appropriate point relative to x and y.  So, if I were to assume that you are anchoring using the upper left corner, and you wanted to place a road to the left of one that is already there, you'd place it at `(x - length_of_new_tile, y)`.  To place it to the right of the old one, it would go at `(x + length_of_old_tile, y)`.  You just use your stored coordinates.

Comment: The same goes for your y values.  To place a tile above the old one, place it at `(x, y - height_of_new_tile)` to place it below the old one, use `(x, y + height_of_old_tile)`.  This assumes a left corner anchor.  Tweak this based on where your anchor is.  I think the confusion on my end was the phrase "detect and teleport to a new canvas image"  If you wanted to place a road on a raw image, you would have to find the roads that are already there first.  If you are just placing roads on your original canvas, just use the x and y values for the last road placed as a reference for the next road.